# iOS Container View loads UIViewController with content goes out bounds

Tags: ios, uicontainerview

I'm loading a UIViewController from storyboard in a Container View but the content appears to start vertically somewhere out fo bounds. Here a simple controller with a view showing a label as example:
[image]

What is causing this? How to prevent it?

Comment: show the code where you load the container please.

Comment: If you use Xcode's view debugging feature, it will show you at runtime where your views are and why (bounds, constraints...).

Answer (score 0):

Found out what was causing it while creating a new project to extract the problem. The view holding the label is inside a scroll view and had its height set to equal the hight of the root view. The root view is however as big as the device's shape and this was what made the content to go out of bounds.